# Can an Android app's service run before it is launched by the user?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

The app has a BroadcastReceiver that listens for a boot-complete event and starts a background service to send some data to my HTTP server.

My question is, if the app is never run by the user (only installed), will the BroadcastReceiver receive the boot event?

Comment: I think from ICS or JB (not sure which) onward you have to run your app at least once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with android 3.1 user has to launch the application once for it to receive the boot_complete broadcast..

Following is from the official javadoc:

> Starting from Android 3.1, the system's package manager keeps track of
>   applications that are in a stopped state and provides a means of
>   controlling their launch from background processes and other
>   applications.
>
> Note that an application's stopped state is not the same as an
>   Activity's stopped state. The system manages those two stopped states
>   separately.
>
> The platform defines two new intent flags that let a sender specify
>   whether the Intent should be allowed to activate components in stopped
>   application.
>
> FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES — Include intent filters of stopped
>   applications in the list of potential targets to resolve against.
>   FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES — Exclude intent filters of stopped
>   applications from the list of potential targets. When neither or both
>   of these flags is defined in an intent, the default behavior is to
>   include filters of stopped applications in the list of potential
>   targets.
>
> Note that the system adds FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES to all
>   broadcast intents. It does this to prevent broadcasts from background
>   services from inadvertently or unnecessarily launching components of
>   stoppped applications. A background service or application can
>   override this behavior by adding the FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES
>   flag to broadcast intents that should be allowed to activate stopped
>   applications.
>
> Applications are in a stopped state when they are first installed but
>   are not yet launched and when they are manually stopped by the user
>   (in Manage Applications).

[javadoc link](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols)

Check out [this blog](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html) for more detail

Comment: @Praful Bhatnagar: can you have a look on my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38611793/does-apps-signed-with-system-signature-can-receive-boot-complete-broadcast-befor

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Boot receiver is registered to listen to the boot so if you reboot your device it will fire, regardless of whether you started the app or not. Similarly, if you add NFC listeners to your manifest, then if someone swipes an NFC card the app will react. The Manifest is used by Android to react to whatever you've specified in it. It's not contingent on whether the app is running (or has ever run).
Excellent question though! :)

**EDIT** as per the other answers and the documentation. This is not true anymore. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Actually, Android 3.1 and above require that the user manually start the app at least once before it responds to any intents or broadcasts.

Comment: interesting. I had not noticed this change.  Good to know!